# Object reference in imported function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a project with a component that imports an anonymous function from another file.

```
import ball from './ball';
export default class Canvas extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {...}
      this.context = {...};
  }
_ball = ball();
_player(){...}
}
```

*('...' = removed code to simplify question)*

Here's a snippet of the imported function:

```
export default () => {
  console.log(this);
  const context = this.context;
  const player = this.player();
  return {...}
}
```

The issue is that 'this' does not refer to the Canvas object. `console.log(this)`returns `undefinded`.

How can I solve this without inlining the function?

Comment: What's the purpose of keeping ball as separate function? You may have XY problem.

Comment: You should simply not use `this` but pass the `Canvas` instance as a parameter to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the context of your class to the `ball` Function when you assign it to `_ball`

Here is an example.

```js
// inline but could be an import/export
function ball () {
  console.log('in ball', this)
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 'hello'
    this.context = 'I am context'
    
    this._ball = ball.bind(this)
    
    this.callBallSomewhereElse()
  }
  
  callBallSomewhereElse () {
    this._ball()
  }
}

new Foo()
```

Alternatively think about passing arguments to the ball `ball` import instead of relying on the whole context being passed to the Function.
I don't know your end-game logic but try keeping functions as dumb as you can, for example by passing `ball` specific arguments instead of binding a whole context Object (`this`) keeps your `ball` Function slim and keeps your Class slim by not assigning `_ball` to `ball` etc.

```js
// inline but could be an import/export
function ball (context, bar) {
  console.log('in ball', context, bar)
}

class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.bar = 'hello'
    this.context = 'I am context'
    
    this.callBallSomewhereElse()
  }
  
  callBallSomewhereElse () {
    ball(this.context, this.bar)
  }
}

new Foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the function you are importing is an arrow function, `this` in that function will always point to the context in which it was defined. You cannot even rebind an arrow function in your `Canvas` class because we cannot rebind arrow functions.

You need to do two things to access `this` referring to the `Canvas` object inside the imported function.

1: 
Change the arrow function that your are importing to normal js function with a function keyword:

```
    export default function(){
    ...
    }
```

2: The line in Canvas class where you are initializing `_ball` with `ball()` function, use javascript `call` method to provide `this` of Canvas class to the `ball()` function.

```
    _ball = ball.call(this);
```

The call() method is used to call a function with any `this` provided as argument i.e.

Making these two changes will make your work and `this` inside your imported function will refer to the Canvas object.

Answer (score 0):

`ball` should be regular function to have dynamic context:

```
export default function () {
  const context = this.context;
  const player = this.player();
  return {...}
}
```

And it should be called with correct context:

```
export default class Canvas extends Component {
  ball = ball.call(this);
  ...
}
```

This is not a conventional way, it requires `ball` to be aware of the context it's used with.

One of more common ways to achieve this with classes is to use a decorator with a mixin:

```
const extendWithBallOrElse = (keyName = 'ball') => Class => class extends Class {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    const context = this.context;
    const player = this.player();
    this[keyName] = ...;
};
```

Which is used like:

```
@extendWithBallOrElse()
export default class Canvas extends Component {...}
```

Or:

```
export default extendWithBallOrElse()(class Canvas extends Component {...});
```